# If $(m,n)\neq 1$, prove $\mathbb{Z}_{mn} \not \cong \mathbb{Z}_{m} \times \mathbb{Z}_{n}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am really struggling with this problem. We just learned isomorphism in rings. We have not learned groups. From reading multiple sources, so far I have:

- Suppose $(m,n) = d > 1 \Longrightarrow \frac{m}{d}, \frac{n}{d}$ integers.
- Suppose $k = \textrm{lcm} (m,n)$, then $k = \frac{m n}{d}$ integer $\Longrightarrow m \vert k, n \vert k$.

How would I proceed from here?

Comment: Count elements of a specific order in each group

Comment: @SeanNemetz We have not had a formal definition of order. What we have learned is that the order of a ring is the size of the set. Is the order the same thing you referred to in this context?

Comment: forgive me. I did not read that you are working with rings.

Comment: @SeanNemetz No worries. I was wondering if there is a way to prove this using a map.

Comment: If you tried proving the contrapositive, you might have more luck .

Comment: Have you guys talked about units in a ring? Counting units might help.

Comment: Yes, we did. Would you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $m,n$ are not relatively prime, then $k = \mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$ is strictly smaller than $mn$.

1. Show that $k x= 0$ whenever $x \in \mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$.
2. Find an element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ such that $k x \neq 0$.

Comment: Sorry I am still having a bit of trouble implementing this. I have the following: $([0]_m, [0]_n) = ([ka]_m, [kb]_n)$. But doesn't using this method require a specific map that maps $[kx]_{mn}$ to $([ka]_m, [kb]_n)$?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. Are you having trouble with proving item 1 or item 2? Or, do you not see how proving those two things will imply the desired proposition?

Comment: Sorry. If I define a map $f(x) = (x,x)$, I can establish this relationship $0 \neq f(kx) = (kx,kx) = (0,0)$. But this only proves that $f$ is not an isomorphism. By definition, if $Z_{mn} \cong Z_{m} \times Z_{n}$, there only need be $1$ isomorphism. So I don't quite see how these two things will imply the desired result.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems like you are getting a bit confused due to the fact that I used $x$ to denote an element of both of the rings under consideration, regardless of what the elements of that ring "look like". This is common practice. Of course, if $x \in \mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$, then we can write $x = ([a]_m,[b]_n)$ (following your notation) and if $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$, we can write $x =[c]_{mn}$.

Comment: Anyway, it might help you to think a bit more abstractly here. Given a ring $R$ and an integer $k$, it is either true or false that $kx=0$ for all $x \in R$. Without worrying about what the elements of a ring "look like", do you understand why, if $R$ and $S$ are isomorphic rings, then either both rings satisfy this condition, or neither ring does?

Comment: That is part of my confusion. I think I don't understand why we can do this: $f([k\cdot 1]_{mn}) = k f([1]_{mn})$. I thought $k$ is a congruence class, but this seems like it is treating $k$ as a scalar multiple of some sort.

Comment: Re: "this seems like it is treating $k$ as a scalar multiple of some sort", that is exactly the right way to be thinking. Given a ring $R$, a positive integer $k$ and an element $x \in R$, one actually *defines* $kx = \underbrace{x+\ldots+x}_\text{$k$ times}$. You can extend this definition to all integers as well: $0x=0$ and $kx = -|k|x$ for $k < 0$. In the particular case where $x = [a]_n$, it's easy to check $k[a]_n = [ka]_m$ as you'd expect. Anyway, main point is that a ring homomorphism $\phi$ (or isomorphism, if that is all you've learned yet) respect this operation: $\phi(kx)=k\phi(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this! Then since an isomorphism $f$ maps the identity to identity, we must have $f(k) = f(k \cdot 1) = k f(1) = k(1,1) = (k,k) = 0$, which is a contradiction. Is this right?

Comment: That's not quite the argument that I had in mind, but also sounds fine. You are proposing to use the fact that $k\cdot 1 = 0$ in one ring and $k \cdot 1 \neq 0$ in the other other ring, and that ring isomorphisms preserve the identity element. It's actually quite easy to see that $k \cdot 1_R =0$ holds in a ring $R$ if and only if $k \cdot x=0$ for every $x \in R$, so the distinction between what I had in mind and what you are doing is really insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

lets prove $mcd(m,n)=1 \Leftrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{m}  cyclic\Leftrightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{nm}  \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{m}$

(first part)($\Rightarrow$)

suppose $\mathbb{Z}_{n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{m}$  not cyclic  and $\mathbb{Z}_{nm}$ cyclic
for every morfism $$f:(\mathbb{Z}_{nm})\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{m}$$
$$1 \rightarrow(g_n,g_m)$$
with $k=ord(g_n,g_m)$ $k\neq \rvert \mathbb{Z}_{n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{m}\rvert =mn$ but $f(k)=(kg_n,kg_m)=k(g_n,g_m)=e$
and $e\neq k$
so f is not inyective and $\mathbb{Z}_{nm} \not \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{m}$

(first part)($\Leftarrow$)

suppose $ord(\mathbb{Z}_{nm})= ord(\mathbb{Z}_{n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{m})=nm\Rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{nm} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{m}$

(second part)($\Rightarrow$)

$be (g_n,g_m)$ the generator of $\mathbb{Z}_{n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{m} \Rightarrow <g_n>=\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ and $ <g_m>=\mathbb{Z}_{m}$

$ ord((g_n,g_m))= min_{k\in\mathbb N}\{kg_n=0_{\mathbb{Z}_{n}},kg_m=0_{\mathbb{Z}_{m}}\}=min_{k\in\mathbb N}\{k\rvert n,k\rvert m\}=mcd(n,m)$

and $ ord((g_n,g_m))=\rvert \mathbb{Z}_{n} \times \mathbb{Z}_{m}\rvert =nm$

so $mcd(n,m)=\frac{nm}{mcm(n,m)}=1\Rightarrow n,m$ are coprimes

(second part)($\Leftarrow$)

n,m coprimes so $ord(1_{\mathbb{Z}_{n}},1_{\mathbb{Z}_{m}})=mcm(n,m)=mn$

Comment: We haven't learned groups yet, but thank you for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

We know that ${\mathbb Z}_{mn}$ is cyclic. So to show that

$$ {\mathbb Z}_{mn} \not\cong {\mathbb Z}_m \times {\mathbb Z}_n $$

it would be enough to show that ${\mathbb Z}_m \times {\mathbb Z}_n$ is not cyclic when $\gcd(m,n) \ne 1$.

Let $\ell=\text{lcm}(m,n)=mn/g$, where $g=\gcd(m,n)$. Thus, $g>1$ if and only if $\ell<mn$.

We show that every $(a,b) \in {\mathbb Z}_m \times {\mathbb Z}_n$ has order dividing $\ell$ when $g=\gcd(m,n)>1$.

Let $(a,b) \in {\mathbb Z}_m \times {\mathbb Z}_n$. Since $m \mid \ell$ and $n \mid \ell$, we have

$$ \ell (a,b) = (\ell a,\ell b) = (0,0). $$

This completes our claim, and the proof of non-isomorphism between ${\mathbb Z}_{mn}$ and ${\mathbb Z}_m \times {\mathbb Z}_n$ when $\gcd(m,n)>1$. $\blacksquare$